# Python excel2img fail: OSError: failed to open clipboard

Tags: python, clipboard, oserror

I'm using python 3 on Windows 11 and I'm writing a code that simply copies excel as images and pastes it on a word document. I'm using excel2img package for doing just that, but the code isn't working and I'm getting the fallowing error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Matheus Seidel\OneDrive\NCEE Meus documentos\Arquivos padrão\Ponte\Pontes - Dimensionamento de viga.py", line 40, in <module>
    excel2img.export_img("Vão 1 - Viga interna.xlsx", "esforços.png", "", "'Esforços solicitantes'!A1:K48")
  File "C:\Users\Matheus Seidel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\excel2img\excel2img.py", line 121, in export_img
    im = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Matheus Seidel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageGrab.py", line 112, in grabclipboard
    fmt, data = Image.core.grabclipboard_win32()
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: failed to open clipboard
```

The same code is working on another windows computer, so it must be a problem on my system, not in the code.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks.

I tried reinstalling excel2img, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I just added the time.sleep(1) function and it worked.

```
def thread_function(name):
global lastcopy
while True:
    curcopy=ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
    if  curcopy != lastcopy:
        pegar_imagen()
        lastcopy=curcopy
    time.sleep(1)
```